# Dúvidas na criação de novas páginas xdk Intel

Tags: intel-xdk

Colegas.

Estou começando agora a mexer no XDK Intel. Meu primeiro APP usei o template de login do programa e está funcionando corretamente. Ajustei conforme abaixo:

```
function signIn(){

            var login=$('#loginAcesso').val();
            var senha=$('#senhaAcesso').val();  

            $.ajax({            
            url:"validar.php",  
            type:"post",                
            data: "login="+login+"&senha="+senha,   
            success: function (result){         
                        if(result==1){                      
                            location.href='sistema/index.html'  
                        }else{   
                            valid_login = false;
                                if(valid_login){
                                    $.afui.loadContent("#main", null, null, "fade");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Example use of the error toast api
                                    var opts={
                                        message:"Login ou senha inválidos",
                                        position:"tc",
                                        delay:2000,
                                        autoClose:true,
                                        type:"error"
                                    };
                                    $.afui.toast(opts);
                                } // fim do valid.login                            

                        }
                    }
        })
        return false;
 } // fim da function signIn()
```

A minha dúvida é:  Para eu criar essa página usando o Template **List View APP**, tenho que criar um novo projeto ou o programa me dá a opção de usar esse template diretamente?

Answer (score -1):

O que você quer é criar uma nova página com um novo template?
Bom se for...
Entrei em contato com a equipe da Intel, pois isso me interessa também, se você observar todas as páginas de login são criadas em um só HTML, portanto, as chamadas são feitas dentro do mesmo.

Uma solução que eles passaram:

- Criar dois projetos;
- Mesclar os códigos;
- Organizar as chamadas de layout;

Aparentemente da certo, fiz aqui e joguei o **listView** no **Start do Template de Login**.

Espero ter ajudado a você e aos demais.

Comment: VNSN, o espaço que utilizou é destinado apenas às respostas. Utilize os **comentários** para questionar por mais detalhes o autor da pergunta.

Comment: é que meus pontos de reputação não permitem... :/

Comment: Pronto, conteúdo editado